# Saving sensor data from IBM Bluemix quickstart into Cloudant NoSQL DB

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant, node-red

I am using IBM Bluemix quickstart in order to display sensor data from Node-red and I am able to see the sensor data coming in real time in Bluemix. However, I would like to save this in Cloudant NoSQL. How can I do this, link the quickstart data to be saved in Cloudant NoSQL DB?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: The Node-RED Quickstart comes with a Cloudant node pre-installed. What have you already tried?

Comment: I didn't have Cloudant pre-installe, so I installed Cloudantplus. And I have a Cloudant database setup in Bluemix. In the cloudant node in node-red I added the database host and name.

But I'm not sure this is the right way to configure it.  Any thoughts? 

Thank you!

Comment: have you included the credentials. see an example, in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cds3ziauml4

Comment: The YouTube video should be helpful. However, in addition, see this information on GitHub: https://github.com/lionelmace/bluemix-labs/tree/master/labs/Lab%20IOT%20-%20Connect%20your%20Devices%20with%20IOT%20Platform

Comment: Also see: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/starters/IoT-starter/iot500.html#before-you-begin